# Is there a more idiomatic OCaml partitioning of needles from a haystack implementation?

Tags: php, ocaml, partitioning

I find myself re-writing this (or similar) functions periodically. I wonder if the stdlib has a more idiomatic solve? As demonstrated below, I opted to use the `containers` lib for some functionality, but suspect the default toolkit may have sufficient, clean powers as well.

> For all x in X, remove/partition first occurrence of x from Y.

The below shows a `exn`-less implementation.

Examples:

```ml
extract [1] [2;1;3]
;; ([1], [], [2;3])

extract [2;4] [2;1;3;4]
;; ([2;4], [], [1;3])

extract [5] [1;2;3]
;; ([], [5], [1;2;3])

extract [1;1;9] [2;3;1;4;1;5;1]
;; ([1;1], [9], [2;3;4;5;1])
```

Assumptions:

- X & Y and not proper sets, but linked collections (e.g. list, array)
- collections are unordered

Implementation:

```ml
(* Given needles and haystack lists, extract needles elements from haystack.
  Produce (successfully_extracted, unsuccessfully_extracted, remaining_haystack) *)
let extract needles haystack =
  let open CCList in
  let f (extracted, needles', haystack') curr =
    match find_idx (Int.equal curr) needles' with
    | Some (idx, v) -> (v :: extracted, remove_at_idx idx needles', haystack')
    | _ -> (extracted, needles', curr :: haystack')
  in
  fold_left f ([], needles, []) haystack |> fun (a, b, c) -> (a, b, rev c)
```

Comment: This function looks very specific and niche to me. And I never personally implemented anything close to it, honestly. So it doesn't surprise me that nothing like this exists neither in the standard library nor in its extensions like Core or Containers. Can you share your user stories? Like when and why you might need such selectors, maybe there is a more natural way to encode your problems.

Comment: Sure! I need to pull needles of a haystack. I have a bucket of things (representing physical or virtual investory), and I get an order. That order of things should be pulled from the haystack's inventory. A haystack could have multiple copies, of something, e.g. the store shelf has N widgets in inventory, and an order only asks for N-1 widgets, so the next haystack will have 1 widget left. Perhaps something is out-of-stock--i want to know what order couldn't be fulfilled.  Perhaps converting to Map type then back is preferred, but my lists are known small.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to represent every widget availability with a number instead of duplicating it? E.g., when my store has a hundred keyboards, I would probably represent it as one article with the availability of 100 items.

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP?

Comment: i wrote this question >2 years ago, i didn't add php tag then. pretty obnoxious that it got added (by someone) then i get downvotes due to someone else's incorrect tagging. you can see revision 1 here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66696967/revisions without the tag

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a particularly difficult problem to solve, if you break it down.

First, in one pass, we can remove a needle from the haystack and determine *if* we removed it.

```
let rec list_remove_first v lst =
  let rec aux lst acc has_removed = 
    match lst with
    | [] -> (List.rev acc, has_removed)  
    | x::xs when v = x -> (List.rev @@ List.rev_append xs acc, true)
    | x::xs -> aux xs (x::acc) false
  in
  aux lst [] false
```

```
# list_remove_first 1 [2;3;4;5];;
- : int list * bool = ([2; 3; 4; 5], false)
# list_remove_first 1 [2;3;4;1;5];;
- : int list * bool = ([2; 3; 4; 5], true)
```

If we can do this, then we can simply fold over our list of needles.

```
let extract needles haystack =
  let (n, n', h) = 
    List.fold_left 
      (fun (needles_found, needles_not_found, haystack_remaining) needle -> 
         match list_remove_first needle haystack_remaining with 
         | haystack', true -> 
           (needle::needles_found, needles_not_found, haystack') 
         | _, false -> 
           (needles_found, needle::needles_not_found, haystack_remaining)) 
      ([], [], haystack) 
      needles 
    in 
    List.(rev n, rev n', h)
```

```
# extract [1] [2;1;3];;
- : int list * int list * int list = ([1], [], [2; 3])
# extract [2;4] [2;1;3;4];;
- : int list * int list * int list = ([2; 4], [], [1; 3])
# extract [5] [1;2;3];;
- : int list * int list * int list = ([], [5], [1; 2; 3])
# extract [1;1;9] [2;3;1;4;1;5;1];;
- : int list * int list * int list = ([1; 1], [9], [2; 3; 4; 5; 1])
```

For the sake of efficiency, we could build a histogram along with indices of the values using a map.

```
module IntMap = Map.Make (Int)
```

```
# [2;3;1;4;1;5;1]
  |> List.to_seq
  |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> (x, i))
  |> Seq.fold_left 
       (fun m (x, i) -> 
          IntMap.update 
            x 
            (function 
             | None -> Some (1, [i]) 
             | Some (count, idxs) -> 
               Some (count+1, idxs@[i])) 
            m) 
       IntMap.empty
  |> IntMap.bindings;;
- : (int * (int * int list)) list =
[(1, (3, [2; 4; 6])); (2, (1, [0])); (3, (1, [1])); 
 (4, (1, [3])); (5, (1, [5]))]
```

We can then rebuild the list from this:

```
# let histo =
  [2;3;1;4;1;5;1]
  |> List.to_seq
  |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> (x, i))
  |> Seq.fold_left
       (fun m (x, i) ->
          IntMap.update
            x
            (function
             | None -> Some (1, [i])
             | Some (count, idxs) ->
               Some (count+1, idxs@[i]))
            m)
       IntMap.empty;;
val histo : (int * int list) IntMap.t = <abstr>
# histo
  |> IntMap.to_seq
  |> Seq.map (fun (k, (count, idxs)) -> List.map (fun i -> k, i) idxs)
  |> List.of_seq
  |> List.concat
  |> List.sort (fun (_, a) (_, b) -> compare a b)
  |> List.map fst;;
- : int list = [2; 3; 1; 4; 1; 5; 1]
```

The trick is updating the histogram in between these two actions. We can use `List.fold_left` to fold over the list of needles, and some `ref` trickery to track the list of found and not found needles.

```
# let nf = ref [] in
  let nnf = ref [] in
  let histo' =
    [1; 1; 9]
    |> List.fold_left
         (fun m n ->
            IntMap.update
              n
              (function
               | (None | Some (_, [])) as i -> nnf := n::!nnf; i
               | Some (count, _::idxs) -> nf := n::!nf; Some (count-1, idxs))
              m)
         histo
  in
  (!nf, !nnf, IntMap.bindings histo');;
- : int list * int list * (int * (int * int list)) list =
([1; 1], [9],
 [(1, (1, [6])); (2, (1, [0])); (3, (1, [1])); (4, (1, [3]));
  (5, (1, [5]))])
```

And re-building the list from the new histogram:

```
let (nf, nnf, histo) =
    let nf = ref [] in
    let nnf = ref [] in
    let histo' =
      [1; 1; 9]
      |> List.fold_left
           (fun m n ->
              IntMap.update
                n
                (function
                 | (None | Some (_, [])) as i -> nnf := n::!nnf; i
                 | Some (count, _::idxs) -> nf := n::!nf; Some (count-1, idxs))
                m)
           histo
    in
    (!nf, !nnf, histo')
    
let new_list =
  histo 
  |> IntMap.to_seq
  |> Seq.map (fun (k, (count, idxs)) -> List.map (fun i -> k, i) idxs)
  |> List.of_seq
  |> List.concat
  |> List.sort (fun (_, a) (_, b) -> compare a b)
  |> List.map fst
```

And `new_list` is:

```
[2; 3; 4; 5; 1]
```

Which gives us the expected data:

```
([1; 1], [9], [2; 3; 4; 5; 1])
```

### Wrapping it all up

These operations on histograms might be encompassed in a functor. And then the needle extraction can be wrapped up in a functor which uses the `Histogram` functor.

```
module Histogram (S : Map.OrderedType) = struct
  module M = Map.Make (S)

  type val_t = S.t
  type t = (int * int list) M.t

  let of_list (lst : val_t list) : t =
    lst 
    |> List.to_seq
    |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> (x, i))
    |> Seq.fold_left 
         (fun m (x, i) -> 
            m |> M.update 
              x 
              (function 
               | None -> Some (1, [i]) 
               | Some (count, idxs) -> 
                 Some (count+1, i::idxs))) 
         M.empty 
    |> M.map (fun (count, idxs) -> (count, List.rev idxs))

  let to_list (histo : t) : val_t list =
    histo
    |> M.to_seq
    |> Seq.map (fun (k, (count, idxs)) -> List.map (fun i -> k, i) idxs)
    |> List.of_seq
    |> List.concat
    |> List.sort (fun (_, a) (_, b) -> compare a b)
    |> List.map fst 
end
```

```
module NeedleExtractor (S : Map.OrderedType) = struct
  let extract_needles needles haystack =
    let open Histogram (S) in
    let nf = ref [] in
    let nnf = ref [] in
    let histo = of_list haystack in
    let histo' =
      needles
      |> List.fold_left
           (fun m n ->
              M.update
                n
                (function
                 | (None | Some (_, [])) as i -> nnf := n::!nnf; i
                 | Some (count, _::idxs) -> nf := n::!nf; Some (count-1, idxs))
                m)
           histo 
    in
    (List.rev !nf, List.rev !nnf, to_list histo')
end
```

```
# let open NeedleExtractor (Int) in
  extract_needles [1;1;9] [2; 3; 1; 4; 1; 5; 1];;
- : int list * int list * int list = ([1; 1], [9], [2; 3; 4; 5; 1])
```